# How to make this JQuery work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm new in JQuery, I found this link: [jQuery Effects](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/02/simple-effects-plugins)

and I want to do the one in which toggles a fade and a slide at the same time (Slide-Fade Togle).

this is the JavaScript code:

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);  
};
```

but I don't know how to make it work. The following is my code for just "Fade Togle" effect:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #Container 
    {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: #e459e9;
    }
</style>

<body>
<button>fadeToggle</button>     
<div id="Container">
    <p>Watch me fade.</p>   
</div>         
<script type="text/jscript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button:first").click(function() {   
        $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow"); 
        $(this).slideDown("slow");
    });
});     
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use the extension you wrote, just have `$(this).next().slideFadeToggle("slow");`

Comment: Why is `asp.net` tagged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the function you defined.  Below works.

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return $(this).animate({opacity: 'toggle', height:'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);  
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button:first").click(function() {   
        $(this).next().slideFadeToggle("slow",'',function(){});

    });
})
```

;

http://jsfiddle.net/caSbk/

Answer (score 3):

It should be `$(this).next().slideFadeToggle("slow");` not `$(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");`

Also, you need to specify all 3 parameters - speed, easing and callback, since you don't provide default values for them.

And make sure that the Javascript function you posted is included somewhere, either as an external file or before `$(document).ready`

Comment: thanks for respond @leo.vingi, but I don't know where to place the function, for instance I placed it in the head section but every time I run the webapp I got "JQuery is undefined"